# How to Enable Internal App Sharing for Android?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-app-bundle, internal-app-sharing

I have uploaded the Android App Bundle in Play console for Alpha testing but when I open the testing URL it is showing below dialog.

[image]

Comment: Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tf79lqnWmrg

Answer (score 396, accepted):

**Try Below Options to Enable Internal App Sharing**

> Option 1

**Step 1:** Open Play store.

**Step 2:** Navigate to Setting. (Click on the account profile picture. which is located at the top right corner of the screen)

**Step 3:** To Enable Developer Options. (Goto > **About** Section. and Tap seven times on the Play Store Version)

**Step 4:** Once you get the “You are now a developer!” prompt, you will see the “Internal App Sharing” option in the **General | User Controls** Section.

> Option 2

**Step 1:** Open Play store.

**Step 2:** Navigate to Setting. (Inside navigation drawer of play store)

**Step 3:** Enable Developer Options. (This is similar to enabling Developer Options within the Android Settings app. Tap seven times on the Play Store Version)

**Step 4:** Once you get the “You are now a developer!” prompt, you will see the “Internal App Sharing” option pop up on your device. Enabling Internal App Sharing will display a warning regarding the internal test nature of the apps that you can now download.

[image]
[image]

Comment: not working anymore for Play Store Version 18.x because tapping the version only checks for updates

Comment: @childno͡.de If your Internal app sharing option already enabled then Play-Store will check for app update otherwise it will enable Internal app sharing option.

Comment: I neither ever enabled this nor is the extra option visible to me. Is it possible that this is caused because I have enabled developer mode on device?

Comment: @VishrutMavani If I already have the live app installed in my phone, will installing Internal app sharing link replace the live app? And, if so, will it automatically get updated to the latest app if I release a production app at a later time?

Comment: @Bob in the Alpha test case: if you have already installed the app & you are opening Internal app sharing link then It will show 2 options. 1st. open the existing app  2nd. uninstall the app.

Note: For alpha testing, you must uninstall the existing app. The internal app sharing link will not automatically update the app.

Comment: Ok but what about Googe TV, I don't see the "Internal App Sharing" after enabling the developer mode

Comment: Blows my mind that this is so hidden. Just why.

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK It has moved to be in a sub-menu now, under General / Developer Options.

Comment: After gaining "developer" status, go to "General" -> "Developer Options" -> "Internal app sharing"

Answer (score 52):

**Steps to enable internal app sharing on Android devices:-**

**1)** Open the Play Store app and tap on the side menu option present in the top right corner (tap the avatar).

**2)** Tap on Settings.

**3)** In the About section, just continuously tap the Play Store Version option for seven times.

**4)** Tap on the General section

**5)** Tap on the Developer options

**6)** Enable internal app sharing option

Comment: I thought the "click seven times" was a joke, it really worked after doing that.

Comment: As of Play Store version 27.1.14-21 [0] [PR] 395979954 the Internal App sharing option is now in the General section.

Comment: As of Play Store version 37.4.24-29 [O] [PR] 563880002 (Two years later!)  the Internal App sharing option is now moved AGAIN,  and is under "Developer Options" section (under General). Their support documentation STILL just says that after you tap 7 times the setting will "appear" (somewhere). Up until this week we have actually *never* had to turn this on so I'm baffled as to why it's only just now required for our app.

Answer (score 9):

**Steps to enable internal app sharing on Android devices:**

**1)** Open the play store app and tap on the USER avatar at the Right Top of the Play Store. It will open the options menu.

**2)** Click "Settings"

**3)** Click the "About" section to expand the "About" Section.

**4)** Now Continuously tap the "Play Store Version" option and you will go to the Developer version.

**5)** Now Click the "General" section to expand it.

**6)** Turn on "Internal app sharing" option from "General"

Answer (score 1):

Before authorized testers can download apps using internal app sharing, they need to turn on internal app sharing on their Google Play Store app.

Open the Google Play Store app Google Play.
Tap Menu Menu > Settings.
In the "About" section, tap the Play Store version 7 times.
After the Internal app sharing setting appears, tap the switch to turn on internal app sharing.
Tap Turn on.

[Read More](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

The [Viishrut answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478895/1843175) helped alot, but didn't fully cover the path for `Samsung mobiles` or maybe `latest android version 13+`. So as a **4th step** this is what I had to do extra. After performing all first three steps the 4th step is below.

**Step 4:** Inside `General`, Scroll down and Tap `Developer Options`. And there you'll see `Interlal app sharing`. Turn that ON.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this was my issue. I think it may be a mix of phone version, Android version, and Play store version. We had never had to even turn this on at all for internal testing until our app targeted Android 13. But indeed once we did (at least on my Android 13 phone) the setting was tucked away inside Developer Options submenu under General section.