# How to Enable Internal App Sharing for Play Store version 34+?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to test an Android app that has been released to the internal testing track. When I tap the app download link it says "Internal app sharing is turned off:"

[image]

However, I don't see an option to enable internal app sharing in Google Play settings.

The instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478894/how-to-enable-internal-app-sharing-for-android) no longer work because tapping the Play Store version now triggers an update.

More info:

- Galaxy S22 device
- Play Store version 34
- The device is already in Developer mode

Is there a new way to enable internal app sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Once in Developer Mode, you should be able to turn on app sharing.  Click on the Google Play Settings link in the message.  Once in the settings, click on Developer options.  Internal app sharing should be in that menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps,

1. Play Store **settings**
2. Select **General**
3. Select **Developer options**
4. Enable **Internal app sharing**